# Out of Bounds Exception in Recursive Merge Sort

Tags: sorting, indexoutofboundsexception, mergesort

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out why I have an Out of Bounds exception in this code. I've tried everything. Eclipse says it occurs at the mergeSortRecursive and merge calls.
Thank you!

//Wrapper method

```
public static <E extends Comparable <E>> void mergeSort (E[]list){
    mergeSortRecursive(list, 0, list.length-1);
}
```

// mergeSort recursive that takes in a left pointer and right pointer, which the wrapper class signifies is 0 and list.length -1

```
private static <E extends Comparable<E>> void mergeSortRecursive(E[] list, int left,
        int right) {
    // Base case
    if (left == right) {
        return;
    }
    int mid = left + right / 2;
    mergeSortRecursive(list, left, mid);
    mergeSortRecursive(list, mid + 1, right);
    merge(list, left, mid, mid + 1, right);

}
```

// Merging the two lists

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void merge(E[] list, int leftFirst,
        int leftLast, int rightFirst, int rightLast) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E[] mergeList = (E[]) Array.newInstance(list.getClass()
            .getComponentType(), rightLast - leftFirst + 1);
    int rightIndex = rightFirst;
    int leftIndex = leftFirst;
    int index = 0;

    while (leftIndex < leftLast && rightIndex < rightLast) {
        if (list[leftIndex].compareTo(list[rightIndex]) < 0) {
            mergeList[index] = list[leftIndex];
            leftIndex++;

        } else {
            mergeList[index] = list[rightIndex];
            rightIndex++;

        }
        index++;
    }
    while (leftIndex < leftLast) {
        mergeList[index] = list[leftIndex];
        index++;
        leftIndex++;
    }
    while (rightIndex < rightLast) {
        mergeList[index] = list[rightIndex];
        index++;
        rightIndex++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i] = mergeList[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked over your code and think that I've gotten the bugs worked out. It looks like there were a number of independent issues that were collectively causing the program not to work correctly.

First, a minor issue: here's your code for making the recursive calls:

```
int mid = left + right / 2;
mergeSortRecursive(list, left, mid);
mergeSortRecursive(list, mid + 1, right);
merge(list, left, mid, mid + 1, right);
```

The operator precedence in the line declaring `mid` is slightly off from what you intended. I think you meant to write

```
int mid = (left + right) / 2;
```

which actually does find the average of the two elements.

The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` you were getting was due to these lines here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i] = mergeList[i];
}
```

The problem here is that `list` is the entire list, not just the part that you were trying to merge with this particular call. To fix this, you can rewrite it like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mergeList.length; i++) {
        list[i + leftFirst] = mergeList[i];
    }
```

This just copies back the part of the array that you merged into the external merge array.

If you make these changes, you'll start getting some weird `NullPointerException`s. The issue is that you're treating the left and right endpoints of the ranges as inclusive bounds, but your merge algorithm treats them as exclusive bounds. You can fix this by changing the conditions on the `while` loops:

```
while (leftIndex <= leftLast && rightIndex <= rightLast) {
    if (list[leftIndex].compareTo(list[rightIndex]) < 0) {
        mergeList[index] = list[leftIndex];
        leftIndex++;

    } else {
        mergeList[index] = list[rightIndex];
        rightIndex++;

    }
    index++;
}
while (leftIndex <= leftLast) {
    mergeList[index] = list[leftIndex];
    index++;
    leftIndex++;
}
while (rightIndex <= rightLast) {
    mergeList[index] = list[rightIndex];
    index++;
    rightIndex++;
}
```

With these changes, everything seems to work!